# Select value from a list from another list HQL

Tags: java, list, hibernate, hql

I have a class with many to many relation.

```
Student class { 
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
private List<Route> routeList;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "idStreet", nullable = false)
private Street idStreet;    
}

Route class {
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "routeList")
private List<Student> studentList;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private List<Street> streetList;
}

Street class {
private long idStreet;
}
```

I need to receive all the routes that have the same locality as the student, with HQL or a function. 
With sql does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with:

```
Query query = entityManager.createQuery("from Route where :code in 
elements(streetList)");
query.setParameter("codigo", idStreet);
```